# Ruby On Rails, Ruby code compilation, encryption?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, source-code-protection

I have developed a tool with ruby on rails, and I want to install my tool on a client in-house intranet. I can deliver an application which protects my Javascript code and sources, but is there a way to protect/encrypt the ruby on rails code? Compile it maybe?